# Does dnode have authentication middleware?

Tags: node.js, express, connect, everyauth, dnode

I'm building an express app that uses everyauth and would like to use dnode. I want to be able to use the `req.loggedIn` boolean set up, but for dnode rpc calls.

Can this be done by having dnode listen to express? Can it access express middleware stuff??

Answer (score 0):

a dnode node can only access objects you've passed during the RPC call. If you would like to share application's auth state, you're free to that.